# How to create a non-binary tree in Java from Array where x denotes null element?

Tags: java, tree

Please help me with code for the following. Thank you!

The input for a tree is shown as a pre-order traversal with null nodes labeled with th character/string 'x'. For example the tree here is characterized by the pre-order string tree = {8, 4, x, 6, x, x, 12, 10, x, x, 15, x, x}

[Picture of tree from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk6B7.png)

Here is the diagram for tree = {5, 4, 11, 7, x, x, 2, x, x, x, 8, 13, x, x, 4, x, 1, x, x}

[Picture of tree 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxhsO.png)

For example, how do I modify the code below (which is for a binary tree) to create a tree as above as I see that 13 is more than 8, so it doesn't seem like a binary tree.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Test data

    // Object[] nums = {"8", 4, "x", 6, null, "x", 12, 10, "x", "x", 15, "x", "x"};
    // Object [] nums = {"1", "x", "x"};
     Object [] nums = { "x" };

    int count = 0;
    TreeCount tc = new TreeCount();

    // Create Tree with the numbers provided
    if (( nums !=null) && (!nums[0].equals("x")) ){
        // Create root node
        int value = Integer.parseInt(nums[0].toString());
        TreeCount.BinaryTreeNode treenode = tc.new BinaryTreeNode(value);

        // Create tree from the values in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < (nums.length); i++) {
                treenode.addNode(nums[i]);          
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" Count = " + count);
}

 class BinaryTreeNode {
    int info;
    BinaryTreeNode left;
    BinaryTreeNode right;
    BinaryTreeNode(int x) {
        info = x;
    }
    BinaryTreeNode(int x, BinaryTreeNode lNode, BinaryTreeNode rNode) {
        info = x;
        left = lNode;
        right = rNode;

    }
    public void addNode(Object a) {

        if ((a==null) ||(a.toString().equals("x"))) {
            return;
        }
        int num = Integer.parseInt(a.toString());
        if (num < this.info) {
            if (this.left != null) {
                this.left.addNode(num);
            } else {
                this.left = new BinaryTreeNode(num);
            }

        } else {
            if (this.right != null) {
                this.right.addNode(num);
            } else {
                this.right = new BinaryTreeNode(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Alright. What have you programmed so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like homework question.

Comment: Homework questions are fine if asked under proper conditions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: These are summer holidays, it is not a homework question. I am still learning java and found an example above that i thought would help me learn from, but don't know how to proceed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP hasn't demonstrated any effort on their part.

Comment: Voted to close as the OP hasn't shown any effort on their part.

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question.

Comment: This is my first time posting in stack overflow, so sorry. I have now posted my code. I would appreciate your expert help, as I am still learning java

Comment: Could you post [mcve]? As posted there are many undefined types and variables.

Comment: *"These are summer holidays, it is not a homework question."* -  Actually, that is not relevant.  The informal rules about "homework" apply to all forms of learning questions, be they formal assignments, homework, optional class exercise or self driven / self-motivated learning.  The actual reasoning is identical for all of them.  You learn more by doing **as much as possible** yourself.  That includes, reading the textbooks, reading the javadocs, reading the stacktraces, reading the compilation errors ... and using a debugger.  These are all things that you need to learn to do.

Comment: Thank you. i have pasted the entire code that I had for a binary tree. But I am stuck on how to create these pre-traversal trees for which I don't see the left node being smaller than the right and also with the pre-string having x, x for null nodes. (as shown in the diagrams)